# Google apps script to delete gmail messages using Google's message ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a list of email ID numbers in Google Sheets that I would like deleted in my Gmail account. I need a script that  will delete all of the listed emails when it is run. The ID number comes from the URL when viewing Gmail in HTML mode. Here is a sample, the 180cd026***9177a is what I have in my list and I need to use to delete the messages from Gmail. The code that I have so far works only if the list of IDs in sheets matches the order of the messages in the inbox.  I need something to work no matter where the message is located in the inbox/list.  Does anyone have suggestions?

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaptwI0-NCgHfOmn5dT1D2okg2vhu_______________________").getSheetByName("sheet1");
     var start = 0;
    var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
      for (var i = 0; i <threads.length; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j<6+1; j++){  // replace 4 with the total values in the google sheet
          var data = range.getValues();
          var iava_value = (data[j][0]);
          var message = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0].getMessages()[0];
         // Get its ID
          var messageId = message.getId();
         console.log(messageId);
         //get thread
         var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
         if(messageId==iava_value)
          {
            thread.moveToTrash();
          }
        }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`getThreadById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getthreadbyidid)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Deletes messages whose ids are in the request array

```
var request = { "ids": idA };
Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
```

Maybe something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaptwI0-NCgHfOmn5dT1D2okg2vhu_______________________").getSheetByName("sheet1");
  var start = 0;
  let idA = [];
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, 100);
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 6 + 1; j++) {  // replace 4 with the total values in the google sheet
      var data = range.getValues();
      var iava_value = (data[j][0]);
      var message = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0].getMessages()[0];
      var messageId = message.getId();
      var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0];
      if (messageId == iava_value) {
        idA.push(messageId)
      }
    }
  }
  if (idA && idA.length > 0) {
    var request = { "ids": idA };
    Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this looks promising, could you tell me where I need to paste these lines of code into the script above?  I really have been just trying to hack together code from github and I'm not too confident with the scripts.  Thank you!  Adam

Comment: You would need to enable Gmail API and whenever you have pushed all of the message ids into idA

Comment: @Cooper : Is it secure to use above script to delete gmail emails permenantly ?

Comment: I don't see why not.  It's all server side